# How add String.equals to java bytecode (Krakatau)

Tags: decompilation, java, byte-code

I use Krakatau to edit java code.

```
class test{

public boolean Func2(String text)
{
    if(text=="aaaaaa")
        return true;
    return false;

}
}
```

When I compile it I get this java bytecode

```
.version 53 0 
.class super [3] 
.super [4] 

.method [5] : [6] 
    .attribute [7] .code stack 1 locals 1 
L0:     aload_0 
L1:     invokespecial [1] 
L4:     return 
L5:     
        .attribute [8] .linenumbertable 
            L0 1 
        .end linenumbertable 
    .end code 
.end method 

.method public [9] : [10] 
    .attribute [7] .code stack 2 locals 2 
**L0:     aload_1 
L1:     ldc [2] 
L3:     if_acmpne L8 
L6:     iconst_1 
L7:     ireturn** 

        .stack same 
L8:     iconst_0 
L9:     ireturn 
L10:    
        .attribute [8] .linenumbertable 
            L0 5 
            L6 6 
            L8 7 
        .end linenumbertable 
        .attribute [11] .stackmaptable 
    .end code 
.end method 
.attribute [12] .sourcefile [13] 
.const [1] = Method [4] [14] 
.const [2] = String [15] 
.const [3] = Class [16] 
.const [4] = Class [17] 
.const [5] = Utf8 <init> 
.const [6] = Utf8 ()V 
.const [7] = Utf8 Code 
.const [8] = Utf8 LineNumberTable 
.const [9] = Utf8 Func2 
.const [10] = Utf8 (Ljava/lang/String;)Z 
.const [11] = Utf8 StackMapTable 
.const [12] = Utf8 SourceFile 
.const [13] = Utf8 'test.java' 
.const [14] = NameAndType [5] [6] 
.const [15] = Utf8 aaaaaa 
.const [16] = Utf8 test 
.const [17] = Utf8 java/lang/Object 
.end class
```

Now I want to replace `text=="aaaaaa"` with `text.equals("ABCD")` 
I know I need to reaplce

```
L3:     if_acmpne L8
```

with

```
invokevirtual java/lang/String/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
ifeq (the line I want to jump)
```

But Krakatau not get this line

```
invokevirtual java/lang/String/equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

what is the right and easy way to replace `==` with `equals` with Krakatau? I dont want to recompile my code .

Answer (score 1):

You need to put spaces between the class name, method name, and method descriptor. Also, you should prefix it with the constant pool type (`Method` in this case). The correct way to write the method call would be

```
invokevirtual Method java/lang/String equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
```

Krakatau will currently accept it if you leave out the `Method` part, but that's not guaranteed to work in the future. Also, for future reference, please post the error you get when asking for help.